# Updated Eclipse, cannot remove Jar

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I deleted a jar from my libs file and now I cannot build the project and the jar will not go away.

I've tried cleaning the project, fixing the android properties now I'm stuck.

Has anyone else had this problem?

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Archive for required library: 'C:/apps/APP/libs/imagecrop.jar' in project 'APP' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file   APP     Build path  Build Path Problem
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove it from your build path. Right click your project, go to Properties->Build Path. The build path contains four tabs:

The Java Build Path properties page contains four tabs:

- Source. The source and output folders. If you initially create a project without separate source and output folders, you can change it here. Multiple source folders can be used in one project; e.g., to separate application source code from unit tests.
- Projects. Check-off other projects in the workspace whose output folders should be added to this build path.
- Libraries. Location of other archive files required by this project.
- Order and Export. Order in which projects and libraries appear in the build path and the default runtime classpath; e.g., use classes from a workspace project before using the same classes from an archive library.

Go to libraries tab and remove the jar file you deleted.

Also refresh your project by right click -> Refresh so it will realize you deleted jar file.

Answer (score 9):

Solution.

Don't use clean or "fix project properties"

Simply right click on the project and press "Refresh"..

Comment: WOW that simple fix my problem after i delete the jar in libs folder +1

Comment: My case was similar, but my project uses Gradle. My resolution required that I right-click my project and select Gradle > Refresh Gradle Project in Eclipse.