# android eclipse removing jar breaks private libraries

Tags: android, eclipse, jar

I'm working with a newbie and somehow the project I'm working on got messed up

Before you think that this is easy I have already tried everything from

[Android Eclipse remove a library project jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12016382/android-eclipse-remove-a-library-project-jar)

[Automatically load libraries on project creating. Android, Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20861752/automatically-load-libraries-on-project-creating-android-eclipse)

[How to attach source to Google Drive API or `Android Private Library` in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16723852/how-to-attach-source-to-google-drive-api-or-android-private-library-in-eclipse)

[Updated Eclipse, cannot remove Jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386198/updated-eclipse-cannot-remove-jar)

[What is the "Android Private Libraries" folder in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20604193/what-is-the-android-private-libraries-folder-in-eclipse)

what's happening is I remove the gson jar file from my libs directory and it breaks the build. I can refresh / clean all I want but it will not build. It is not in the Android tab or in the build path anywhere except for where you see it in the photo below. I want the library gone and I still want to be able to build. any help?

[image: eclipse photo]

Comment: Have you restarted Eclipse?

Comment: haha, thanks @CommonsWare . I guess it's been a long day. if you want to post it as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the going gets tough, the tough restart Eclipse. It's like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Del</kbd>, just for your IDE.

Seriously, Eclipse sometimes gets confused and works better when it can reload its internal object model from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on project > Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
It worked for me.